# Good practices for creating a new projects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need to create a new website, I have the database modeling done and I need to start it, I also want to use MVC and LinqToSql.

My boss said that I'll might need to create an app for Windows Phone 7.

I never follow any good practice or pattern when I'm working on this, what I mean is, when a user clicks a Register button in a web page, I create an instance of my DataContext, validate the input and etc all inside the event handler for that button click.

So, what about when I need to make the WP7 app? I'll have to copy and paste the code again? I know that I should reuse it, but I don't know actually how, where should I place the business rules, data access etc...

I was reading about Enterprise Patterns, but I found it too complicated for me as I don't have much experience yet.

Please advice me on this.

Also, if you can point me to a good sample project that I can check its source code and follow the same architecture, would be great!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MVP design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx) is what you're looking for !

I'm in a similar case (an application shared between mobile & Desktop on different screen sizes / frameworks) and by using this pattern the Business code is the same and you don't need to duplicate your code.

Answer (score 3):

Sharp architecture is a well known sample of MVC architecture and project structure.

http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/(X(1)S(rcnk1jfg1daywk55iazwqh55))/default.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Of course, you may set up your project differently depending on your needs, but this is a great example to start with.

Also, for data access, the Repository pattern is widely used. Here is a good article for implementing the pattern in MVC using Entity Framework...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

You should look at moving to N-tier design, separate your UI from the Biz from the Dal.
This also allows reuse of your biz logic and Dal in the phone app, or any where else you might need to.

Here is a blog post that kind of covers what you are going to need to do [N-Tier Design revisit](http://bob-the-janitor.blogspot.com/2009/07/n-tier-design-revisit-part-1-over-view.html) this is the first of 5 posts covering N-Tier design, I include some code samples and have some projects to look at in the repository.

Another suggestion is to get a copy of [Head First Design Patters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) to learn design patterns, and start looking at learning best practices.  Good design is technology agnostic, you should spend as much time learning how to design something as you do what you're building it in.

Comment: nice avatar bob. same as on your blog huh +1 for the nice article

Answer (score 0):

One good thing about using MVC is that your actions can actually return JsonResult, and become an exposed service API for your WP7 client app.

I would suggest looking into that, along with what stephen776 has suggested; your MVC app would then be the one to consume your Repositories (Data Access) and Entities (Model), and then expose them to both web browsers (using MVC Views/Javascript) and external apps (using JSON results).

For the WP7 app, the best pattern to use is called Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) and it relies in a powerful Silverlight feature called DataBinding, try looking into that as well. There exists a good set of libraries aimed to help you with that http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/